# Left Bitshift operation. Is this calculation correct?

Tags: c, bit-shift

What is the result of the following bitshift operation:

```
  ((((uint32)   0x0) << 6U) |  
   (((uint32)   0x2) << 4U) |  
   (((uint32)   0x0) << 2U) |  
   (((uint32)   0x1) << 0U))
```

I would expect:

0|32|0|1 = 33 decimal

Is this right or I'm totally wrong?

Comment: Have you tried compiling and running a test program?

Comment: Explain us how exactly you came to this result. Doing so you'll probably find out by yourself if your answer is right or wrong.

Comment: No, it is **not** *right* and no you are **not** *totally wrong*. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala interesting comment, but too vague. Do you mind to explain better?

Comment: @linuxfan then it would be an answer.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala no, it could be a right answer, or a wrong answer, or an out-of-topic one. Put this way, it is only useless irony, I think.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala `<<` It is not right, but it is left? Yeah that's right, it is left. And what is left after that is of the same type as the promoted left operand. Right?

Comment: @Lundin I mean that `33`/`32` is obviously wrong, but OP is not totally wrong :P. In any case this is a mental typo and should be closed as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the code and see for yourself. Let me write a `printf` statement for you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main (void)
{
  printf("%u\n",   
    (((uint32_t)   0x0) << 6U) |  
    (((uint32_t)   0x2) << 4U) |  
    (((uint32_t)   0x0) << 2U) |  
    (((uint32_t)   0x1) << 0U) );
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, hopefully `"%u"` matches `uint32_t`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I purposely did not want to confuse the OP with inttypes.h while they are still learning about `printf`.

Comment: `<inttypes.h>` not necessary as the arg could be cast to `unsigned`.  IAC, answers are not just for OP.  But all a minor issue anyways.